# JQuery UI Datepicker reinitiate when a change has occurred with another date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

So I am working with JQuery Datepicker, now I have 2 fields one for start date and one for end date. I am looking to make it so when the start date has been entered the end date can then be entered but must be after the start date. Now this I can do, however how can I go about if the start date has been changed that the date has changed in the end date.

Im not overly familiar with how this would work once a plugin has been initiated.  I initiate it like this:

```
$( ".endDate" ).datepicker({
  beforeShowDay : noWeekendsOrHolidays,
  dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
  minDate: new Date(<?=$start_date?>),
  maxDate: new Date(<?=$yearend?>,<?=$monthend?>,<?=$dayend?>)
});
```

Can I do something like overwrite the min date at a later time so maybe I can add a change function to the start date so that it changes the min date again? but how after the plugin has been initiated can I overwrite the `minDate` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change any jQuery UI option in the following way:

```
$('.endDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', newValue);
```

That's a feature of the widget factory that jQuery UI uses.

Also, see the sample in the [datepicker documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate).